# stdout does not display `rpm -qa` output without redirect

Tags: rpm, sles, stdout, sles12

On a SLES 12 virtual machine the command `rpm -qa` does not return anything to stdout.

```
~> rpm -qa
~>
```

The command finishes after 1 or 2 seconds, so it clearly generates some data. Only when the output is redirected to a file or through a pipe it becomes visible:

```
~> rpm -qa > out.txt      # works fine
~> rpm -qa | grep lib
libgcc ...
...
```

The problem is not with the rpm DB, the DB files in `/var/lib/rpm/` are existing and seem healthy, a rebuild as suggested [here](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000017180) does not solve the problem.

Comment: maybe your shell is broken. Try `reset`. or just login again.

Comment: Thank you, but I now discovered it was apparmor's fault :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the rpm apparmor profile which caused this behavior. I disabled it temporarily and rpm worked again.